# changing panel color

Tags: java

i have a string which stores the name of a color. Through the help of this variable i need to change the panel background. how can it be done???

Comment: Is the number of color names you're working with finite?

Comment: yes. but the problem is that there are many programs linked with each other, and once the color is changed in one form the same color is to be used in the other form also

Answer (score 2):

Create Map which contains the String name of the color and the actual Color object.

Edit:

Just noticed two other answers suggest using the getColor(...) method. That does not just magically work and you need to define the color in the system properties. I've never used system properties, but I believe you need to set them when you start the JVM.

Comment: +1 for the map response - since there are a finite set (according to a comment from the OP) I would strongly recommend following this mechanism.  This allows you to change the colors (as mentioned by the OP) and for that change to be received by others once the change happens - i.e. the next time they request that color.

Answer (score 1):

If the colors are only going to be the ones that java supports, you could do something like the following:

```
private Color getColorByName(String colorName) {

    Field[] colorFields = Color.class.getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : colorFields) {
        if (field.getName().equals(colorName.toUpper())) {
            //check that this is in fact a static field,
            //to make sure it is one of the colors you are looking for
            int modifiers = field.getModifiers();
            if ((Modifiers.STATIC & modifiers != 0) 
                    && (Modifiers.PUBLIC & modifiers != 0)) {
                try{
                    return (Color)field.getValue(null);
                } catch (FieldNotFoundException ex) {
                    //Maybe put some additional handling in here if you need it
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //or return a default color
    return null;
}
```

A few notes:

1. This uses reflection, so it will
   be slower (although you could,
   technically use this to make a color
   map at startup of the application
   and just reference that).
2. It would make a lot more sense to make
   a color map as mentioned by other
   people above.
3. The best would be
   if the different systems sent you
   actual values - say rgb values in
   int or 0.0-1.0 double format.  Then
   you could consistently give them the
   appropriate response.

My recommendation, if you must use the color name, would be that they give you a set of names you must support, and you have an error condition - either a default color, null, or throw an exception.

Hope this helps.